# Как отсортировать элементы прямоугольной матрицы [n*m], которые параллельны главной диагонали, по невозрастанию?

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы

Возникла проблема с сортировкой элементов диагоналей прямоугольной матрицы, которые параллельны главной диагонали матрицы. Известно же, что главной диагональю матрицы является диагональ, которая начинается в верхнем левом углу матрицы и изменяется вниз и вправо, пока не будет достигнут правый или нижний край матрицы. Получается две диагонали тогда в прямоугольной матрице? И как это рассчитывать в динамическом двумерном массиве? И как отсортировать (выбором и вставками) в коде элементы диагоналей, которые параллельны главной диагонали матрицы?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning ( disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

void ru_lang() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
}

class sort {
private:
int l, w;
float tmp;
public:
float** fill_matrix(char* name, int& n, int& m) {
    string input = name; //Здесь просто вводится название файла
    ifstream file(input);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Файл не открывается." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    file >> n;
    file >> m;
    w = n;
    l = m;
    float **matrix = new float*[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new float[w];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
        {
            file >> matrix[i][j];
            //cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; //Проверка на тот случай, если не работает вывод матрицы
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return matrix;
}
void show_matrix(float** matrix) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Длина матрицы: " << w << endl;
    cout << "Ширина матрицы: " << l << endl << endl;
    cout << "Матрица: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


/*float selection_sort(float** matrix) { //Сортировка выбором (непонятно пока, как сделать)
for(i = 0; i < n-1; ++i){
key = 0;
k = i;
a = A[i];
for(j = i+1; j < n; ++j){
if(A[j] < a){
k = j;
a = A[j];
key = 1;
}
}
if(key){
A[k] = A[i];
A[i] = a;
}
}
return **matrix;
}*/


/*float insertion_sort(float** matrix) { //Сортировка вставками матрицы (тоже пока непонятно)
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
float* a = matrix[i];
for (int j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (a < matrix[j]); j--)
matrix[j + 1] = matrix[j];
matrix[j + 1] = a;
}
return **matrix;
}*/
};

int main() {
ru_lang();
char name[80];
float** matrix;
int len, wd;
class sort Go;

cout << "Добро пожаловать в нашу программу!" << endl;
cout << "Введите название файла: (Как вводить: *название*.txt) (Пример: matrix.txt)" << endl;
cin >> name;
matrix = Go.fill_matrix(name, len, wd); //(1) Чтение из файла
Go.show_matrix(matrix); //(2) Вывод матрицы на консоль
//Go.selection_sort(matrix); //(3) Сортировка выбором (первый метод)
Go.show_matrix(matrix); //(4) Вывод матрицы на консоль
matrix = Go.fill_matrix(name, len, wd); //(5) Чтение из файла
Go.show_matrix(matrix);
//Go.insertion_sort(matrix); //(7) Сортировка вставки (второй метод)
Go.show_matrix(matrix);
system("pause");
}


Input.txt
4 3
1 2 9 3
-1 7 4 -11
3 -5 1 3


Output.txt //Должно так получится
4 3
1 2 9 3
-1 7 4 3
-11 -5 1 3
```

Comment: *"диагональ, которая начинается в верхнем левом углу матрицы и изменяется вниз и вправо, пока не будет достигнут правый или нижний край матрицы. Получается две диагонали тогда в прямоугольной матрице?"* - почему две? Угол то у вас один ;-)

Comment: *как отсортировать (выбором и вставками) в коде элементы диагоналей, которые параллельны главной диагонали матрицы?* ??? Сам же пишешь - "выбором и вставками". Сливаешь диагональ в вектор, сортируешь, возвращаешь - делов-то...

Comment: сортировать по невозрастанию возможно по бесконечным количеством критериям...